How to customize this DIY intervalometer for Nikon P900?
Like many others before me, I would like to take interval shots with my Nikon P900 with intervals of less than 30 seconds, preferably around 2 seconds.
I have already searched a lot on the internet, but there is no good solution for this.
However, an existing Photo-SE question discusses it: How can I shoot time lapses with Nikon P900 beside the built-in 10 seconds programs?
An answer there links to a guide for a DIY intervalometer:

If you don't mind a bit of DIY, Limor Fried (Lady Ada) at Adafruit Industries has posted a fairly easy walkthrough of creating an intervalometer that emulates/replaces the ML-L3 using an Arduino kit, IR LED, and a couple other simple parts.

Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with remote triggers/remote control. As far as I can tell, this DIY device can only turn the camera on and off. Is that correct? To what extent can I use it to set the interval for the shots to, say, 5 seconds or less?
I would be very grateful if someone could explain whether and how I can set the interval to less than 30 seconds with this DIY device.

Basics of DIY electronics, such as PWM signaling, is off-topic for Photo-SE. If you have specific questions about the linked DIY project, perhaps they are on-topic for [electronics.se].


As far as I can tell, this DIY device can only turn the camera on and off. Is that correct?

No, the camera must already be on. It sends IR pulses (on/off) at the correct frequency to trigger the shutter.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain whether and how I can set the interval to less than 30 seconds with this DIY device.

The program is set on a loop with a 1 minute interval; but you can chage that delay to whatever you want.
void loop()                     
{
Serial.println("Sending IR signal");

SendNikonCode();

delay(60*1000);  // wait one minute (60 * 1000 milliseconds)
}

